# Parseerror and Jquery was not called

Tags: jquery, jruby, jsonp, jquery-1.7, parse-error

I'm using the Jruby version 1.6.6. Jquery verison 1.7.
And got some Data online whit a Ruby applikation:
http://churbackend.impac.ch/news

Now I want to read the Json out of this data.
my request is like:

```
    var test = $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    url: "http://churbackend.impac.ch/news.json",

    success: function(data) {
        alert('Success!');
    },
    error: function(xhr, error, stack) {
      alert(error);
      alert(stack);
    }
});
```

I get 2 alerts back :
The first (error): parseerror

And the second (stack): jQuery17036032104332288495_1329118955821 was not called

my news_controller looks like this:

```
 def index
    @news = News.all
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.json { render :json =>  @news }
    end
  end
```

I tried verious diffrend things, like "text json" and almost all of the solutions whitch I found in diffrent forums. But nothing could help me solved my problem.
If you know how to deal whit this please help me, or if you need more informations just ask (I'm a beginner in forumposts)
Best wishes 
Luca

Edit:
I got a solution for the parseerror:

```
new news_controller:
  def index
    @news = News.all
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.json { render :json =>  @news }
      format.js { render :json =>  @news,  :callback => params[:callback] }
    end
  end
```

It works whit this ajax request:

```
var test = $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    url: "http://localhost:3000/news.js",

    success: function(data) {
        alert('Success!');
    },
    error: function(xhr, error, stack) {
      alert(error);
      alert(stack);
    }

});
```

But I got a final question:
How can I get this working whit a getJSON request?
At the Moment it fails and just gives a empty string out.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.getJSON('http://localhost:3000/news.js', function(data) {
        alert(data);
         $.each(data, function(i, entries)
                 { 
                     $('#maincontainer').append('<div class="AccordionTitle">'
                     +'<h2>'
                     + entries.title
                     + '</h2>'
                     +'</div>'
                    );
                   });
    });
});
```